# obtener un valor X Y de un GrindPane

Tags: java, javafx

```
    Grindpane.getChildren().forEach((Node node) -> {

    int rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == null ? 0 : GridPane.getRowIndex(node);
    System.out.println("Este nodo está en la fila n° " + rowIndex);

    int columnIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == null ? 0 : GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
    System.out.println(" y en la columna n° " + columnIndex);

    });
```

Lo que necesito es que al momento de hacer click en alguna de la matriz que tengo creada con un brindPane de 5 x 5 obtener el valor X Y Del arreglo pero con este código recorre todo la matriz

Comment: Creo que hay un error debe ser gridpane no grindpane

Answer (score 0):

**Obtener columna y fila de GridPane con evento de mouse click**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estaba muy lejos , salvo que su bucle itera sobre todos los nodos indistintamente.
En esta respuesta se usa el evento [setOnMouseClicked](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setOnMouseClicked(javafx.event.EventHandler))(javafx 17).
Cuando el usuario hace click sobre un nodo se obtiene la columna y la fila con los métodos estáticos  `GridPane.getColumnIndex(Node)` y`GridPane.getRowIndex(Node)` respectivamente .

Este es un ejemplo en una sola clase que usted puede probar

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var column = new Label("columna");
        var columnText = new Label();
        var box1 = new HBox(20, column, columnText);
        var row = new Label("fila");
        var rowText = new Label();
        var box2 = new HBox(20, row, rowText);
        var grid = getGrid();

        grid.setOnMouseClicked((t) -> {
            Node intersectedNode = t.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
            int rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(intersectedNode) == null ? 0 : GridPane.getRowIndex(intersectedNode);
            rowText.setText(String.valueOf(rowIndex));

            int columnIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(intersectedNode) == null ? 0 : GridPane.getColumnIndex(intersectedNode);

            columnText.setText(String.valueOf(columnIndex));

        });

        var scene = new Scene(new VBox(20, box1, box2, grid), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private GridPane getGrid() {

        var grid = new GridPane();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                grid.add(new Circle(30, Color.SEAGREEN), i, j);

            }

        }

        return grid;

    }

}
```